# Prevent user to be logged in on two or more clients simultaneously Web Api 2 Oauth 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I've been searching all over for a solution for my problem to prevent users to be logged in on two or more clients simultaneously. 
Is there some way to invalidate all particular users access tokens when user signs in?

Thanks

Comment: wouldn't simply logging out the user on sign-in (if they're already logged in), then logging them back in issue a new token and invalidate the old one?

Comment: That will not work since I don't have the user in the context while I'm logging him in.